# Taming 'span' classes in twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with span4. when I add class with padding to that div(my_background_plate), I no longer get 3 divs in a row but 2 (that padding pushes the last span4 to a new row). How to compensate?

```
 16   <% @projects.each do |p| %>
 17     <div id="projects" class="my_background_plate span4">
 18       <h3>
 19         <%= link_to p.name, project_path(p) %>
 20       </h3>
 21       <p>
 22         <%= p.description %>
 23       </p>                 
 24       <img src="http://placehold.it/205x140" alt="" class="thumbnail">
 25       <p>
 26         <% p.users.each do |u| %>       
 27           | <%= u.name %>
 28         <% end %> |        
 29       </p>
 30     </div>
 31   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer whill wrestiling with it a bit. The whole magic is to leave the div with span class free from you custom classes and add them below in a separate div like below. :)

```
 17     <div class="span4">    
 18       <div id="projects" class="my_background_plate">
```